# Loopback: 401 Authorization Required after successful login

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am currently facing an issue where I always get a 401:

For example when I try to do a GET request to /users/{id}/customer I am getting the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:430:21\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/loopback/lib/model.js:358:7\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/loopback/common/models/acl.js:529:16\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3874:9\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16\n    at iteratorCallback (/var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1050:13)\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3871:13\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/loopback/common/models/acl.js:511:17\n    at /var/www/p-web-2-api-node/node_modules/loopback/common/models/role.js:442:21\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:176:11)"
  }
}
```

I have acquired the correct token through login, I have set the token in the /explorer (which is added as a query parameter) but the 401 always shows up.

When I disable the server.enableAuth(); in /boot/authentication.js it works. I have tried acl's and have either removed everything or granted $everyone full access.

Comment: Post your `loopback:security:*` debug string https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html

Comment: I also ran into this when lauching some projects in NODE_ENV=production and I couldn't figure out why. The only tricks that was working for me is to set User's, ACL's and AccessToken's datasource with my custom database, and not the base 'db' memory from Loopbackjs.